# Connect to "real" aws dynmodb from local lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-sam

I have built a simple lambda with SAM

handler:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("start here")
    client = boto3.client("dynamodb", region_name="us-east-1")
```

template:

```yaml
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambda/
      Handler: MyLambdaFunction.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Events:
        MyLambdaFunction:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: cron(0 0 1 * ? *)
```

and try to run it locally with sam (using this solution [How to connect RDS instance when running SAM locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798633/how-to-connect-rds-instance-when-running-sam-locally/54857559))

```
sam build --use-container
sam local invoke --no-event --docker-network host MyLambdaFunction
```

but got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.35/networks/95139d2edc48f8f7962cefa291649ec668663f9a1c0f609b56725f3c62f9fe8e/connect

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/sam", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('aws-sam-cli==1.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'sam')()
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metrics.py", line 96, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metrics.py", line 62, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 86, in cli
    parameter_overrides,
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 151, in do_cli
    context.function_name, event=event_data, stdout=context.stdout, stderr=context.stderr
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 100, in invoke
    self.local_runtime.invoke(config, event, debug_context=self.debug_context, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/local/lambdafn/runtime.py", line 83, in invoke
    self._container_manager.run(container)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/manager.py", line 93, in run
    container.create()
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/container.py", line 138, in create
    network.connect(self.id)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/models/networks.py", line 57, in connect
    container, self.id, *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/network.py", line 249, in connect_container_to_network
    self._raise_for_status(res)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("container cannot be disconnected from host network or connected to host network")
```

It seems I can not connect to cloud dynamodb (not a local mock dynamodb) from my local lambda.

How can I access data in dynamodb from local lambda with SAM ?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you experiencing a specific error? :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams  I am getting "timeout" on lambda

Comment: so I assume dynamodb is not accessible from local lambda started by sam

Comment: You would set it as a local DynamoDB in the SDK (which you've not). Is your code able to speak out to the internet at all? It runs on a Docker container so wondering if the networking for your container has not launched properly :(

Comment: @ChrisWilliams    thanks for the reply :)   I do not want to use local dynamodb because real data in on aws. I also suspect my code can not speak to the internet, but  I found no solution how to set the network properly with command "sam local invoke".

Comment: What type of environment are you in (Windows/Linux). Sometimes for Windows launching Docker/Virtualbox require running as Admin

Comment: @ChrisWilliams  I am on aws ec2  "Amazon Linux 2"

Comment: Can the EC2 speak outbound?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams  yes. It can

Comment: Hmm, have you configured any credentials within the SDK? I wonder if it’s retrying in a failure

Comment: @ChrisWilliams  good point. I am using IAM Role on ec2

Comment: That would not fall down to the Docker container, it would need credentials :(

Comment: @ChrisWilliams   you are right. I set access_key_id and secret_key on boto3 client now. Sadly that doesn't solve the problem. I think the issue --docker-netowork host here doesn't work

Comment: Yeah it seems like it :(