# How to connect a lambda to a database accessible locally on Mac's localhost when using sam

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-sam-cli

### Background

- I have a lambda that is connected to a RDS database. The RDS database and lambda are in a VPC. The db is only accessible to developers via a Bastion instance.
- During development we can test the lambda using [sam](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-invoke.html). This works fine for APIs that don't depend on the database.
- For APIs that depend on the database, I would ideally like to connect to the database instance running in our Gamma stage. However, we can't directly connect to it because it is in a VPC.

### What I have tried

- To get around this, we can use the SSM agent on the bastion instance with port forwarding so that the database is accessible on our Mac's localhost. See [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#sessions-remote-port-forwarding). Sample code below:

```
aws ssm start-session --target <instance-id> --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost --parameters host="mydb.example.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",portNumber="3306",localPortNumber="3306"
```

- I can now connect to this locally at `http://127.0.0.1:3306/` via CLI or a GUI like [PSequel](http://www.psequel.com/).  No need to use SSH.
- However, if I try to get the lambda to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:3306/`, I get the error `Connection refused`.
- My understanding is that this is because `127.0.0.1` resolves to the docker container's localhost rather than my machine's localhost.
- According to [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host), `host.docker.internal ... resolves to the internal IP address used by the host`
- However, if I try to get the lambda to connect to `http://host.docker.internal:3306/`, I get the error `Name or service not known`.

### Minimal Working Example

I have created a MWE at https://github.com/bluprince13/sam-app-connect-to-host-localhost. Instead of trying to connect to a database, we can just run a Python server locally, and try to get the lambda to connect to it.

### Question

- How to connect a lambda to a database accessible locally on Mac's localhost when using sam?
- I'm open to any alternatives for testing our lambda locally. Deploying to AWS is too much of a pain even with [cdk hotswap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-deploy).

### References

- [[Question] Is it possible to connect to a database running on localhost? #2272](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2272)
- [Cannot call API running on separate localhost port #260](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/260)
- [How to connect RDS instance when running SAM locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798633/how-to-connect-rds-instance-when-running-sam-locally)

Comment: If I understand correctly - you have an RDS instance in a VPC in a private subnet and a proxy server in the same VPC that is in a public subnet (is publicly accessible) and is proxying the requests to the private RDS instance. Instead of using SSM to map localhost to it, can't you call the proxy server directly?

Comment: Did you try to use your host IP?

Comment: When I tried your MWE using `sam local start-api` it worked fine. If that code fails to run in your mac, I think the difference is laptop configuration. Can you specify the version of macOS, docker, SAM etc.? Also I have a SAM setup which connects to RDS in a private VPC. That also works fine in my mac. I'm using `host.docker.internal` to connect to localhost of the host.

Comment: @LLL - No - my lambda doesn't know how to create a ssh tunnel - it wouldn't need to in prod, and therefore it shouldn't need to in local testing. By creating a SSH tunnel using SSM, I can get my locally running lambda to speak to the database as though it were directly connected to it.

Comment: @Anton using host IP does not work. I get error `No connection adapters were found for '1<MyIP>:5000'

Comment: @user11666461 - just tried this on my personal Mac and it did actually work!!! Thank you so much. That means something's wrong with my work Mac setup.

Comment: Work laptop env (where it doesn't work): macOS 12.3.1, docker 20.10.17, sam 1.60.0.

Comment: @user11666461 on my work mac, the docker configuration (Docker -> Preferences -> Docker Engine) was overridden. Specifically, the `dns` key. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/. After I removed it, everything worked fine with `host.docker.internal`. Thank you so much! Do you want to provide an answer or shall I write it up myself?

Comment: Hey I may be late, but "we can't directly connect to it because it is in a VPC", why not? I have had RDS and Lambda in VPC before. Is your lambda NOT in vpc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MWE provided looks correctly configured. The issue is with docker configuration. **As OP could figure out, there was a `dns` override in the configuration. (Docker -> Preferences -> Docker Engine) was overridden.** After removing it, everything worked fine with `host.docker.internal`.

In general, to connect to the localhost of your host machine from a container you have to use `host.docker.internal` in **mac** and **windows**. Refer the SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/43541732#43541732) for configurations in other platforms. Specific to SAM in macOS, it is advisable to have the following, to avoid hard coding of parameters:

1. Create an `Environment` variable in `template.yaml` under your resource property.

```
  Properties:
     Environment:
       Variables:
         DB_HOST: *your_database_url*
```

2. Create an `env.json` file with following configuration.

```
   {
    "*Logical_ID of your resource*": {
        "DB_HOST": "host.docker.internal"
     }
   }
```

3. Run your SAM with the `env.json` as `sam local invoke --env-vars env.json`.

Comment: @blueprince13 Thanks for letting me write the answer. Added some config changes that was not available in your MWE (May be you are already doing it this way in your real code). Feel free to edit the answer to add your findings or changes that you did to make your container listen to localhost.